# REST API wrapper design

Tags: php, oop, rest, design-patterns

I'm writing a wrapper (Adapter pattern) for a number of REST calls. I'm trying to decide how much my response object should be able to do.

```
class Job
{
    private $xml;
    public function __construct(SimpleXMLElement  $xml)
    {
        $this->xml = $xml;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->xml->Name;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->xml->ID;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

class RESTManager
{
    private $client;
    public function __construct(Guzzle $client)
    {
         $this->client = $client
    }
    public function getJobByName($name)
    {
         $job = $this->client->get('/query/job/' . $name);
         return new Job($job->asXMLObj())
    }
}
```

So I have something similar to the above. Once I have the Job object I will want to get some additional information such as, a list of items in the Job. This requires another server call
Should I ask the Job what the items are

```
class Job {
    private $manager;
    ...
    ...
    public function addManager(RESTManager $manager)
    {
         $this->manager = $manager;
    }
    public function getItems()
    {
         return $this->manager->getJobItems($this);
    }
}
```

or
ask the RESTManager directly?

```
class RESTManager {
    ...
    ...
    public function getJobItems(Job $job)
    {
        return $this->client->get('/job/' . $job->getId() . '/items');
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see why this is REST... What about the HATEOAS constraint?

Comment: I'm using the Guzzle library to encapsulate the calls to the server. client->get() is the request to the REST server.

Comment: Yes, but you should use the links sent by the server, instead of building URLs in your clients. This is against what REST is.

Comment: Totally agree with @inf3rno. There is not REST here. If you are working with collections and XML(which is rather old-fashioned) you should really look into some collection patterns like Atom-Pub or Odata. Consider these patterns and you would not waste time for solving problems that are already solved several times.